# Custom comparison function for SORT in C++ STL?

Tags: c++, sorting, stl

I am using

```
       typedef pair < long , pair <bool ,long > > t;
       vector <t> time ;
```

and I need to sort the above vector using `std::sort()` function but using a a customized comparison function. I wrote a version of it but is not working properly. Can you please point out my mistake?

```
     bool comp ( const t &a , const t &b){

         if ( a.first < b.first)
             return a.first > b.first ;
         else if ( b.first < a.first )
             return b.first > a.first ;
         else if ( a.first == b.first )
         {
             if ( a.second.first == false && b.second.first == true)
                return a.first > b.first ;
             else if ( a.second.first == true && b.second.first == false)
                return b.first > a.first ;
             else
                return a.first > b.first ;
          }
      }


      inside main(){
         sort ( time.begin() ,time.end() ,comp) ;
      }
```

Custom Case:

Before sorting : vector time

```
       10 1 1 
      100 0 1
      100 1 2
      200 0 2
      150 1 2
      500 0 2
      200 1 2
      300 0 2
```

After Sorting:

```
      10 1 1
      100 0 1
      100 1 2
      150 1 2
      200 0 2
      200 1 2
      300 0 2
      500 0 2
```

Comment: This question could use an English-language description of exactly how you need these things sorted -- ie: what makes one `t` "less" than another.  The code seems a bit confused about the issue.

Comment: Please indent your code properly, it’s currently unreadable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your comparison function doesn't define an ordering.  In fact,
it seems to return true any time `a.first != b.first`.

I'm not sure what sort of custom order you want.  The standard
ordering of std::pair will result in something like:

```
bool
comp( t const& a, t const& b )
{
    if ( a.first != b.first )
        return a.first < b.first;
    else if ( a.second.first != b.second.first )
        return a.second.first < b.second.first;
    else 
        return a.second.second < b.second.second;
}
```

It's actually a bit more complicated, since the only comparison
operator it uses is `<`.  But if `<` and `!=` are both
available, and behave normally, the results are the same as the
above.

You can easily adopt this to compare the elements in whatever
order you want; if you want to inverse the order for one of the
elements, just replace `<` with `>`.

And finally, `false` compares less than `true` for boolean
values.

Comment: I'd say it returns false for a.first != b.first.

Comment: @KitFisto On studying it further, I'd say that it always returns `false`.  If `a.first == b.first`, all of the return paths are either `a.first > b.first` or `b.first > a.first` as well.  (I still can't figure out what he's trying to do.)

Answer (score 3):

It should be:

```
if ( a.first < b.first)
    return true
else if ( b.first < a.first )
    return false;
// etc.
```

In your version it returns false in both cases.

Comment: To clarify: if `a.first < b.first` is true, then `a.first > b.first` will be false (and vice versa) unless `<` and `>` are defined strangely.